# Python colorama print doesn't work well

Tags: python, colorama

I don't know how this type of Question is called but here it is.
I've programmed a function to display the given list as in the middle using escape sequences. All worked fine in the console. But when I run the Program as a file It doesn't worked.

```
from colorama import *
import time
from blessings import Terminal
init(autoreset=False)
t=Terminal()
l1=["Such middle. Much center.","I <3 Python","Unicorn power all over the world"]

def strcenter(l):
    strc=[]
    e=int(int(int(t.height)-int(len(l)))/2)+1
    for i in range(1,e):
        strc.append("\n")
    if (e % 2 == 0):
        for p in l:
            pc=p.center(t.width," ")
            strc.append(pc+"\n")
    else:
        for p in l:
            pc=p.center(t.width," ")
            strc.append(pc+"\n")
        strc.append(" ".center(t.width," ")+"\n")
    for i in range(1,e-2):
        strc.append("\n")
    return "".join(strc)


print Style.BRIGHT+Back.WHITE+Fore.BLUE+strcenter(l1)+Style.RESET_ALL
time.sleep(5)
```

Thanks.

Comment: _But when I run the Program as a file It doesn't worked_ What does "run the Program as a file" mean?

Answer (score 2):

As [per the docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama), `colorama` only works in the terminal, not when run in IDLE, (probably what you mean when you say *run the Program as a file*). This is by design and you cannot make `colorama` work from inside the IDLE.